# Calendar days diappearing from Apple Watch

Tags: calendar, apple-watch

My Apple watch regular loses the ability to show me calendar appointments for a day, roughly once a week. I've tried Watch->General->Reset->Reset Sync Data multiple times to no avail. Whenever this happens, the day in question is just invisible to the watch. The calendar appointments are visible to the calendar on my iPhone, but not the watch. Other days are visible while this problem is occurring, but not the "bad" day. I have multiple calendars connected to my iPhone (work Exchange calendar, personal GCal, etc.), and they're all missing the same "bad" day.

The really strange thing is that I get notifications for the appointments on that day. I have a 2:30pm CDT appointment today that's got a 15 minute reminder on it, and it's going to trigger at 2:15pm CDT today. This frequently, but not always, occurs on Fridays, as it is today. The watch is just saying "NO MORE EVENTS".

If anybody has any ideas or paths to try in debugging, I'm all ears, eyes, and fingers.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but I have found nearly all the weird bugs in Apple Watch are resolved by simply rebooting the watch. Have you tried this? Hold down both buttons until you see the apple logo

Comment: Yes, I've tried rebooting the phone and watch, both.

Comment: You say "I have multiple calendars connected to my iPhone (work Exchange calendar, personal GCal, etc.), and they're all missing the same "bad" day." This means the issue is not only on your Watch but on your iPhone, too.

Comment: @fsb, suggesting what? I can see the appointments on my phone just fine. What should I look at next?

Comment: I'm trying to clarify the problem you have.  Is your Watch set to mirror your calendars and your calendar entries?

Comment: Custom. There are more calendars on my phone than I want to see on my watch, so I only have 3 out of 7 or so enabled.